python matplotlib 3D bar chart invert log scale axis
I have a problem with a bar chart in 3D using matplotlib : I want to invert the z axis of this graph :enter image description here
(note that to make the log scale, I am just taking the log of my function)
But if I do this with ax.set_zlim(-15, 0) I get this graph :
enter image description here
What I want is that the bars start at -11 and end at their value. Is there any way to achieve this ? Thanks in advance !

Minimum reproducible example is missing. Please add code and fake data if you cannot include the real one.
